# Linebreaks in TinyMCE editor show extra line on preview, not in code

Tags: tinymce, bbcode, rte

I'm using the BBCode plugin with TinyMCE and see that line breaks are not showing the same between the preview and the HTML code.

I have the following lines in the editor window:

```
This is line one

This is line three
```

Line two is empty. When I'm viewing this in HTML I get the following.

```
This is line one
This is line three
```

Without the extra empty line.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "bbcode",
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    remove_linebreaks : false,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    forced_root_block : ''
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the raw HTML output look like, and do you get the same result if line 2 has a space in it?

Comment: No, if line 2 contains a space, I get the result i want: <Line1><Empty line><Line2>. But I don't want a space - just an empty line! ;-)

Comment: I suspect tinymce is outputting <br><br> but some web browsers will only display 2 consecutive linebreaks if there is whitespace between the two HTML tags. Hence my test..

Comment: ..and i was wrong. Problem seems to be that when text is extracted from the textarea (either by posting, or getContent() ) any double newlines are transparently converted to single newlines by the web-browser. Only way i can think of working around that is hacking TinyMCE to always place a space immediately before any newlines.

Comment: @Kordonme: Have you already tried my testpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested it on [my test page](http://www2.alpinechough.com/tinyMCE_BBCode_example/) with Firefox 3.5.7 and Google Chrome 4.0.223.11.

html:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  theme : "advanced",
  mode : "textareas",
  plugins : "bbcode",
  content_css : "bbcode.css",
  entity_encoding : "raw",
  add_unload_trigger : false,
  remove_linebreaks : false,
  apply_source_formatting : false
});
```

The space between the paragraphs can be removed using a simple CSS ("bbcode.css") like this:

```
p {margin:0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: It's the output I want correct, not the preview. See the example link and try what I wrote in my post :-)

Comment: Ok, here we go:
a) open link "http://flipfish.dk/examples/", type something into the editor, press "Submit", got "404 Page not found"
b) open link "http://flipfish.dk/examples/", type something into the editor, click on "Test"-Link
My solution is for b): the alert-window shows me the empty line.

Comment: Hi Anderas. Just for clarity; I didn't downvote you :-) Second, the solution you provided didn't work. I get a linebreak. But I'm looking for an empty line.

Comment: @andreas: I tested it and it works, but I think the OP is asking how to preserve the empty lines upon form submission. TinyMCE seems to be making some kind of post-processing there.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Let's change the theme to "advanced" -> click on "HTML"-Button -> same result (empty line)

Comment: @andreas: Again, the problem is not within the RTE editor, it's the Javascript post-processing that removes the empty lines, try adding the action attribute to your form and post it to a PHP page, the newline won't be there.

Comment: @Alix Axel: submit-button added -> newline is there.

Comment: @andreas: Dude, it's not about the submit button... The form does nothing as it is, **try processing it with PHP**.

Comment: @Alix Axel: The first php keyword is in your comment in your answer. I don't think the OP has a problem with php. You haven't missed my "submitted data"-section on my test-page?

Comment: @Alix Axel: update: result.php added; **Still** **working**. I can't see your point...

Comment: @andreas: Seems to be working as it should, let the OP know about that.

Comment: @andreas: This workd 100% as expected. How can I mark your answer as correct now? :S

Comment: @Kordonme: To mark my answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: @andreas: There's no green check mark, since the question had a bounty and it autoaccepted the answer with most upvotes.

Comment: @Kordonme: ... then the bounty expires with no auto-accept, and no answer can ever be accepted for that question. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to **[use the `nl2br()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)** to output your HTML code:

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks
>   before all newlines in a string

Alternatively you could set the `force_p_newlines` option to `true`.

---

I've tested it and you're right but the behavior only happens with the BBCode plugin. I believe that by using the `preformatted : true` option in `tinyMCE.init` you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: No - this isn't in any way the problem I'm describing. First of all, this happens with the built in BBCode previewer, too. And I DO get a linebreak. But I want two, as i typed in the editor: <Line1><Empty line><Line2>. force_p_newlines to true has no effect. I will provide an example. See edit in original post.

Comment: The preformatted property had no affect, either :( Starting to think this just might be a bug or maybe even by design!

Comment: @Kordonme: Yeah and it's impossible to reliably undo the effect with PHP. I'm sorry but I can't think of anything else, I've read TinyMCE wiki and some forum posts but no solution comes to my mind... Maybe you should try asking this on the TinyMCE forum?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought at first. But the support forum had one post with the first line being: "We can not possibly provide support for free for everyone, this forum is closed for posting."

Comment: @Kordonme: That's sad. They should change that to: "We can not possibly provide support for free for **anyone**, this forum is closed for posting." Have you considered switching to CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

From TinyMCE configuration you can choose the beavhior of newlines

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines

> TinyMCE will force BR elements on newlines instead of inserting paragraphs

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x
});
```

Comment: Hi! You almost had me there for a second: remove_redundant_brs. But it didn't work :( It's actually doing something else: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/remove_redundant_brs

Answer (score 1):

FYI -- despite the political drama around it being the "right thing to do" to use `<p>` tags and not use `<br>` tags, the issue for me was that I was sending content out in emails -- and in emails, I don't have control over CSS on the `<p>` tags (unless I want to add inline CSS to every tag). So the `<p>` tags were adding what appeared like double line spacing for end-users. I had added the CSS on my site to remove the spacing and the content looked fine there.

So after using `<br>` tags, then going to the "right way" with `<p>`, I'm going back to using `<br>` tags again...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing this. Just change the behaviour of Enter and Shift+Enter Keys.

```
ed.onKeyPress.add(
    function (ed, evt) {
            if(evt.shiftKey && evt.keyCode == 13) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<br><br>');
                tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(evt);
                //alert('shift enter key');
                return;
            } 
            if(evt.keyCode == 13 && !evt.shiftKey) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<br>');
                tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(evt);
                //alert('enter key');
                return;             
            }                
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding in the config object

```
valid_elements: 'br'  //and any others that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This is a solution for bbcode plugin:

```
forced_root_block : false,
remove_redundant_brs : false,
valid_elements: "br",
verify_html : false,
```

Answer (score 0):

with TinyMCE 4 i have the same problem but for me working this config

```
mode: 'exact',
inline: true, 
add_unload_trigger: false, 
schema:"html5", 
invalid_elements: "span", 
extended_valid_elements : "span[!class]", 
paste_remove_styles: true,
forced_root_block : false, 
verify_html : false,
cleanup : true
```