# TinyMCE BBCode removes trailing extra line/space

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, bbcode, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE 4.x version, BBCode as a source in my project. Below is the TinyMCE init code for it,

```
            tinymce.init({
                mode: "textareas",
                editor_selector: "mceEditor",
                resize: "both",
                forced_root_block: false,
                remove_redundant_brs : false,
                verify_html : false,
                force_br_newlines: true,
                force_p_newlines: false,
                remove_redundant_brs : false,
                remove_linebreaks : false,
                valid_elements: 'br',
                plugins: ["autolink link image anchor bbcode code noneditable"],
                toolbar: "bold italic link | code | bbcode",              
        });
```

If I add newline or extra line/space at the end of content and trying to get content from javascript(`tinyMCE.activeEditor.getElement().val()`), the content got is in trimmed form. Is there anyway to stop trimming the right trim of the content while we get content from TinyMCE?

I have tried different options from this: [Linebreaks in TinyMCE editor show extra line on preview, not in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969335/linebreaks-in-tinymce-editor-show-extra-line-on-preview-not-in-code), [tinymce remove text spaces and line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104384/tinymce-remove-text-spaces-and-line-breaks) link but options does not worked for me.

Does anyone has an idea what changes that I need to make to overcome from this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
solved it with hakish solution ( no tinyMCE documentation for it anywhere) adding below settings inside tinymce.init({... solve the issues for me

```
indent_before: 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,div,title,style,pre,script,td,th,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,area,table,thead,' +
                    'tfoot,tbody,tr,section,article,hgroup,aside,figure,figcaption,option,optgroup,datalist',
                indent_after: 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,div,title,style,pre,script,td,th,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,area,table,thead,' +
                    'tfoot,tbody,tr,section,article,hgroup,aside,figure,figcaption,option,optgroup,datalist',
                whitespace_elements: 'p pre script noscript style textarea video audio iframe object code',
```

indent_before, indent_after - I removed the p element from that list and left all the default I have found in tinymce.js source file.
this stopped putting space before and after each p.
whitespace_elements - I added the p element to that list and left all the  default I have found in tinymce.js source file. this stopped removing trainling spaces in the begining of P element